# Looking up another table for values in multiple columns (SQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I am currently using PostgreSQL and having a table as such:

[image]

There are 3 columns which contains the location ID which is linked to a location table. In the location table there is location_id and location_name. Is it possible to create a query that would allow me to display the location_name instead of the location_ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multiple left joins:

```
select bt.transaction_id, 
       bt.datetime, 
       l1.location_name as location_1_name, 
       l2.location_name as location_2_name,
       l3.location_name as location_3_name
from base_table bt
  left join location l1 on l1.location_id = bt.location_1
  left join location l2 on l1.location_id = bt.location_2
  left join location l3 on l1.location_id = bt.location_3
```